How to add headers in angular for httpclient
I had added the headers in the following way,

  getdataForFilters():Promise<IFilterResponse> {
     return this.httpClient.get<IFilterResponse>(this.url + '/filters', this.headers).toPromise();
  }

    Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type  ....

Seems like after adding headers I am getting the error at interface. Should i also need to add header data in my interface? Can anyone please help.

This is a TypeScript error, can you please show the full error? Also please add the definition of this.headers

The get(url, options) method takes two arguments; the string endpoint URL from which to fetch, and an optional options object to configure the request.
And the optional options object has the following key value pairs,
options: {
  headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
  observe?: 'body' | 'events' | 'response',
  params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>},
  reportProgress?: boolean,
  responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
  withCredentials?: boolean,
}

And also it is suggested to NOT to use toPromise() method. The recommended way of doing it as below,
getdataForFilters():Promise<IFilterResponse> {
    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            clientId: 'AHJIUE'
        })
    }

    const apicall$ = this.http.get<IFilterResponse>(this.url + '/filters', options);
    return (firstValueFrom(apicall$));
 }

your import statement,
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

Note: And also check your IFilterResponse interface which has necessary key value pairs.
